# Tree size in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have an implementation of a tree like this:

data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a] deriving Show

and I need to get the size.

I think this code can resolve this problem but I have an error:

```
size :: Tree a -> Int
size Empty       = 0
size (Node a ts) = 1 + [size t | t<-ts]
```

Comment: You're trying to add a number and a list. Can you think of a way to *sum* the numbers in a list?

Comment: but this kind of list return an int no?

Comment: There are no lists that "return" an int. A list is a list.

Comment: I Think you should first define what you mean by size. Is it the depth of the tree, the number of elements or even something else ?

Comment: On your question, you should not post commented code. And you should give us your error message.

Comment: Number of elements

Comment: As a side note, your definition of tree is a bit odd to me, I think it's a bit error prone, because you can have two terminal cases, for example `Empty` and `Node 1 []`

Comment: That's pretty normal, @Jean-BaptistePotonnier. You want a way to have zero-element trees as well as one-element trees, and the Node constructor in `Node 1 []` has the element `1` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size:: Tree a -> Int
size Empty = 0
size (Node a ts) = 1 + maximum[size t | t <- ts]
```

probably you want the max size of the subtrees so I would use the function predefined maximum to get it after convert every branch into his size.

Comment: it's the depth, with maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

```
> 1 + [2,3,4]
<interactive>:8:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [t]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t. (Num [t], Num t) => [t]

> 1 + sum [2,3,4]
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have a typing error in your code.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Int]’
• In the expression: 1 + [size t | t <- ts]
  In an equation for ‘size’:
      size (Node a ts) = 1 + [size t | t <- ts]
```

Since you want an `Int`, you have to find a way to convert your list of `Int` to an `Int`.

In other words, you can introduce a hole like this :

```
size :: Tree a -> Int
size Empty         = 0
size (Node a ts) = 1 + _g [size t | t<-ts]
```

leading to the error message :

```
• Found hole: _g :: [Int] -> Int
  Or perhaps ‘_g’ is mis-spelled, or not in scope
• In the expression: _g
  In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘_g [size t | t <- ts]’
  In the expression: 1 + _g [size t | t <- ts]
• Relevant bindings include
    ts :: [Tree a]
      (bound at /Users/jeeb/incubator/scratch/app/Main.hs:10:14)
    a :: a (bound at /Users/jeeb/incubator/scratch/app/Main.hs:10:12)
    size :: Tree a -> Int
      (bound at /Users/jeeb/incubator/scratch/app/Main.hs:9:1)
```

Depending of what you mean by "size", you should be able to  replace `g` by the correct function.